# Pointers vs. double pointers for buffers

Tags: c, pointers

I have a situation where I have a large-ish string in memory and I want to serve out slices of this with functions (eg. give me a 14 char run starting at 30).  To make this work, I had to have consumers use a double pointer for their buffer.

```
void foo(char** bar)
{
    char* tmp = "nope";
    *bar = &tmp[1];
}

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char* baz = "yep";
    foo(&baz);
    printf("%s", baz);
    return 0;
}
```

However, if I look at various library functions like pread or strcpy they accept string buffers with just one pointer level.

How are they doing that? It seems like they should need a double pointer as well to change the value "on the other side" in the same way.

Comment: "It seems like they should need a double pointer as well to change the value" - nope. One level of indirection is enough, they don't change the pointer, only the values pointer to by the pointer.

Comment: When you set `*bar` to `&tmp[1]`, you're pointing it to an automatic (stack based) variable that will go out of scope when _foo_ returns.  Did you want to fix that?

Comment: This is sample code.  It's a multi-megabyte binary blob on the heap in the real code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most such functions don't change pointers, they change memory. The prototype of `strcpy()` is:

```
char * strcpy(char *dest, const char *source);
```

This means that the memory pointed at by `dest` will be overwritten with content from `source`, up until (and including) the first 0-character is found.

The caller will call this with the address of a buffer that is going to be modified.

For your case, it sounds like you're after *zero-copy* string slicing, then it makes more sense to use pointers to pointer. Note that the termination will become an issue though, you can't slice a C string without needing to copy since otherwise the original will be sliced too.

You could of course define a copying string slicing function:

```
char * slice_string(char *dest, size_t dest_max,
                    const char *source, int start_index, int end_index);
```

This will copy characters from `source` into `dest`, just like `strcpy()`, but only copy a sub-string. I made the indices signed so you can support negative indexing á la Python, for instance.

Note that the function isn't called `strslice()`, since that function name is reserved.

Answer (score 3):

Both [`pread()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pread.html) and
[`strcpy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcpy.html) do not change the place that the pointer points at; they change the content that the buffer contains.  Therefore, they do not need the double pointer notation.

You'd likely do best with:

```
const char *foo(void);
```

This avoids the double pointer, and would allow you to write:

```
char *baz = foo();
```

in your example main program.

Representing string slices without null termination will require some care (a start position and a length).  Maybe you'll use a structure with a pointer and a length, in which case, you can either pass a pointer to such a structure to your function, or return a copy of the structure.

Answer (score 2):

You need to differentiate between the pointer and the pointee. Consider a function taking a single-level pointer called like this:

```
char *p = ...;
f(p);
```

`f` receives a copy of `p`. This copy points to the same memory as `p` does, so `f` can change the values in the memory `p` points to, but it can **not** change *which* piece of memory `p` points to. In contract, a function accepting a double pointer is called like this:

```
char *p;
g(&p);
```

`g` will be able to do everything `f` could do, using `*the_parameter` (which gives the value of `p`). But *in addition*, it can change `p`, so it can make `p` point to some different piece of memory. This is not necessary for most functions, but it's sometimes useful.